# Trying to push Deploy to Firebase Hosting merging to main branch and giving me a Error: Process completed with exit code 254

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, npm, deployment

I just deployed my project using firebase and now when I try to merge to `main` it's giving me the following error, it would mean lots to me if someone can help me with this issue, I have been trying to figure it out for the past day without any success. this is the full error that I'm getting

```
Run npm i && npm run build
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/amazon-clone/amazon-clone/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/amazon-clone/amazon-clone/package.json'
npm WARN amazon-clone No description
npm WARN amazon-clone No repository field.
npm WARN amazon-clone No README data
npm WARN amazon-clone No license field.

up to date in 0.629s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/amazon-clone/amazon-clone/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/amazon-clone/amazon-clone/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-01-01T23_26_07_370Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

Comment: Your package.json seems to be gone. Is it still there at the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

npm install is unable to find the package.json file. Please make sure it exists in the root folder of your repository. (And is under version control and valid).